How do we handle huge gzipped file dropped to S3 for AWS/Databricks ingestion?
I find some interesting suggestions for posted questions. Thanks for reviewing my threads. Here is the situation we have. I am not a Databricks expert and looking for suggestions/directions for our  situation.
We are getting data feed from on-premises to AWS S3 for Databricks ingestion, where a data feed is able to push data in only gzip format. When the dropped files are huge in s3 bucket/folder (eg over 20GB).
The uncompressed file is delimited by '|'
We are facing loading challenges into Databricks. Our current Databricks autoloader takes very long time with risk of retry upon failures of this load. It is throwing memory error after running for awhile. It is look like spark is poor of handling gzip files.
If we add a decompress step and pass decompressed file to auto loader it works ok with parallelization.
We know other databases have bulk load options with Parallel split/distribution to handle this situation. 

Do we have such or better options in Databricks?

Are we able use Databricks external table to tie AWS S3 gzip file with partition option? Will this help/work?


The Databricks developers are proposing the following:

Do we need to go to upstream on-premises data push process and ask for dropping files in smaller sizes (eg 4gb) into AWS S3? ‌‌

I see the standard way for this described as:

"Read the Gzip File from S3: Use boto3 to read the gzip file from S3
and load it into your Databricks environment." - source network/Generative AI

How did folks in this community address these issues in a smart way?
Thanks for your guidance.

What is the file format inside the gzip file? For example, is it Parquet or CSV? Also, where did you find the "Use boto3 to read the gzip file from S3 and load it into your Databricks environment" advice? Can you point us to page?

I did edit my post for further clarity and addressed your question. What was reason behind this question?

I asked because it is strange to say that boto3 should be used to read a gzip file. Boto3 is the AWS SDK for Python. It can be used to call AWS services, including uploading files to S3, but offers no capability around interpreting or transforming the contents of a file. I'd say that AI doesn't quite know what it is saying. You could create an External Table with a configuration that uses a pipe-delimiter, but a single 20GB file is always going to be slow to process.

Another option is to use Amazon Athena to read the file and convert it into a Parquet format that will be much faster to use. For some examples, see: Using AWS Athena To Convert A CSV File To Parquet | CloudForecast and How To CSV 2 Parquet — AWS Athena | by Sergio | Medium.

How did you find Athena based solution ? It looks promising. I am not sure, why Generative AI did not pick this one.  We have Athena available only on Sandbox. It is not enabled in other ENV (TEST/PROD etc) Are there ways to achieve the same without using Athena?

Amazon Athena processes data in Amazon S3. There is no concept of a 'sandbox' in Athena.
